# Create a pdf with dynamic values and the send the pdf as a email attachment using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, email, pdf

I want to send a simple mail with php.
First i have to create a PDF file with some dynamic values, then i have to send the pdf as a email attachment to a email id.
I am using php mysql for it.
I already try with fpdf class, but not getting proper result.
Please give me some suggestion or some code samples, so that i can understand it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use tcpdf library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDFTK is the library I use.

I recently completed a project similar to this, users filled out a form, data was stored on database, PDF was generated from these database values and filled out the PDF, PDF was then sent to their email as an attachment.

You can get the resources and tutorials you need from here
https://github.com/andrewheiss/pdftk-php

Answer (score -1):

try this library it's awsome,just pass html to this library

https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/